# Install Windows 10 on MacBook Pro 2017 (14,1)

Tags: macbook-pro, bootcamp

I had already figured out that I must use bootcamp assistant to install windows 10 on my MacBook Pro 2017 14,1 , otherwise if I just boot into a windows installation USB,it can't get my internal keyboard, touchpad and the PCIe SSD.
Does anyone know how to install it without using the assistant?

Comment: Are you trying to install Windows as the only operating systems on your Mac?

Answer (score 1):

BootCamp assistant is just a utility to make it easier to install Windows on a Mac.

It packages the Windows installer onto a Thumbdrive and *slipstreams* the drivers to support Apple hardware into the installation so you don't have any non-working devices during boot. It also presents a nice simple GUI to re-partition your HD/SSD.

If you are comfortable installing the necessary drivers (at least keyboard and trackpad/mouse) **into** a bootable Windows 10 installer then I say, "Go for it."

But I do Windows support for a living and I don't bother with that and frankly don't know *HOW* to do that. Honestly you are better off just using BootCamp assistant, it is easy and practically foolproof.